# Class form-control does not allow hidden textbox to be hidden in html

Tags: php, html, jquery

Class `form-control` does not allow hidden textbox to be hidden in HTML,
I tried something like this

```
<input type="number" name="mfi_nam9" class="text1 form-control" id="mfi_name" hidden>
```

But it does not work, except when I remove form-control

I want to use it in below codes

```
<table>
<?php
for($count=0;$count<=2;$count++)
{
 echo"<tr>
    <td>
      <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"sd3\" value=\"mfi_nam9\" class=\"checkme\" />
    </td>
    <td>First Value</td>
    <td>
      <input type=\"number\" name=\"mfi_nam9\" class=\"text1 required form-control\" id=\"mfi_name\" hidden>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>";
}
  ?>

</table>



<script>
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.checkme[type="checkbox"]'), function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.text1[type="number"]').hidden = !this.checked;
  });
})
</script>
```

Comment: dude....where is sample code

Comment: How is this php related?

Comment: Why do you want to hide the input? Can you not use <input type="hidden" name= ....

Comment: even when I use <input type="hidden" name= ... it does not work when I check checkbox

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden` for class instead id

```
.text1 {
   display: none !important;
}
```

or

```
.text1 {
   visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Seems like you are using same id for many elements inside for loop.

Comment: I tried to use display: none; or visibility: hidden but when I check checkbox nothing changed